# Can javascript switch execution before a try block?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Let's say I have the following code in javascript:

```
ajaxRequest(function(response) {
    console.log("Response 1 happening");
    console.log("Response 1 continuing");
});

ajaxRequest(function(response) {
    console.log("Response 2 happening");
    console.log("Response 2 continuing");
});
```

Now presumably responses 1 and 2 could happen in any order, but we would expect that they could not be *interleaved*, which is to say the execution wouldn't switch in the middle of code. And JS isn't threaded, so they can't execute at the same time.

However, (specifically on Chrome) if I change the second request to:

```
ajaxRequest(function(response) {
    console.log("Response 2 happening");
    try {
        console.log("Response 2 continuing in try block");
    }
});
```

I sometimes see:

```
Response 2 happening
Response 1 happening
Response 1 continuing
Response 2 continuing in try block
```

Should this be possible? If so, when can the JS interpreter switch what code is executing?

I should say that this isn't actually my code (which involved a fair bit of computation in between statements), but I've tried to reproduce the key parts. (The asynchronous behavior is caused by a combination of AJAX requests and `setInterval` calls.) If this shouldn't be possible, I may have misinterpreted some of what's going on, but I don't believe I've missed anything.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: doesn't happen, no

Comment: Also the Chrome console itself can do some interesting things.

Comment: No, there's nothing asynchronous about `try`.

Comment: No, `try` is not an event.

Comment: Are there any `alert()` calls?

Comment: @Pointy What do you mean exactly?

Comment: If this is actually happening, then it is an illusion caused by Chrome's `console.log()`, not by `try`.  try is not async and does not allow context switching to another event.  If you show a jsFiddle that demonstrates this happening, we could likely offer more info.

Comment: @1252748 The Chrome console is not really synchronous. I'm not exactly sure what the precise behavior is, but there are commonly-seen effects that suggest that to be so.

Comment: @Pointy, I thought it might just be the byproduct of console buffering. I still thought it was worth asking because the code is also behaving as if it's executing interleaved. I'll take a more careful look and try to repro.

Comment: Bah, ok thanks for your help everyone. Looks like there was a hidden callback in the code causing the appearance of interleaved code. It was interacting with, but ultimately unrelated to, the asynchronous code.